# monitor node-opc-ua events

Tags: node.js, events, opc-ua, node-opcua

I'm trying to monitor events (instead of variables) from a OPC-UA server using [node-opcua](https://node-opcua.github.io/).

I did not found any example of monitoring events in the [client tutorial](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/v2.1.3/documentation/creating_a_client_typescript.md) and found some old issues like [this](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/245) online and some [sample code](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/0583488cfd1602ffd41bf17d8c548ba1dff75b52/packages/playground/sample2Subscriptions.ts#L93)

Based on what I see it seems like "monitoring" an event should be quite similar to monitor variables: I need to change the attributeId from `AttributeIds.Value` to `AttributeIds.EventNotifier` in the `ReadValueIdOptions` parameter, add a `filter` variable in `MonitoringParametersOptions` object and then call a method like `ClientMonitoredItem.create`, passing a subscription, or directly calling `monitor` method on the subscription itself.

I'm testing code with an online demo server `opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:62544/Quickstarts/AlarmConditionServer`, and I'm able to monitor a variable like "LastSeverity" by its nodeid, which I found by using the UAExpert client. :

[image: UA Expert screenshot]

I get the following output if I run the source code posted below

```
PS PATH_TO_DIRECTORY> node out/main2.js
17:46:03.763Z :opcua_client_impl             :248
Warning: endpoint_must_exist is now deprecated, use endpointMustExist instead
session created !
Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed:  300
Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed:  500
Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed:  700
Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed:  900
Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed:  100
```

main2.ts source code:

```
import {
    AttributeIds,
    ClientMonitoredItem,
    ClientSubscription,
    DataValue,
    MessageSecurityMode,
    MonitoringParametersOptions,
    OPCUAClient,
    OPCUAClientOptions,
    ReadValueIdOptions,
    SecurityPolicy,
    TimestampsToReturn,
} from "node-opcua-client";

async function main(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const options: OPCUAClientOptions = {
            connectionStrategy: {
                initialDelay: 1000,
                maxRetry: 100000,
            },
            securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.None,
            securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.None,
            endpoint_must_exist: false,
        };
        const client = OPCUAClient.create(options);
        await client.connect("opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:62544/Quickstarts/AlarmConditionServer");
        const session = await client.createSession();
        console.log("session created !");
        const subscription = ClientSubscription.create(session, {
            requestedPublishingInterval: 1000,
            maxNotificationsPerPublish: 100,
            publishingEnabled: true,
            priority: 10
        });
        const itemToMonitor: ReadValueIdOptions = {
            nodeId: "ns=2;s=1:Metals/WestTank?Bronze/LastSeverity",
            attributeId: AttributeIds.Value
        };
        const parameters: MonitoringParametersOptions = {
            samplingInterval: 100,
            discardOldest: true,
            queueSize: 10
        };
        const monitoredItem = ClientMonitoredItem.create(
            subscription,
            itemToMonitor,
            parameters,
            TimestampsToReturn.Both
        );
        monitoredItem.on("changed", (dataValue: DataValue) => {
            const value = dataValue.value.value;
            console.log("Monitored item value (LastSeverity) changed: ", value);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Execution failed: ", err);
    }
}

main();
```

So the variable monitoring is fine, but I can't succeed in monitoring an event. If I add Event View in UAExpert I can see a lot of events:

[image: UA Expert events description]

By changing the code in something like the following (I also tried a very similar code to the first I posted, by changing `AttributeIds.EventNotifier` and stuff like that as I said above), nothing happens and no events are logged on console:

```
import {
    AttributeIds,
    ClientSubscription,
    DataValue,
    MessageSecurityMode,
    OPCUAClient,
    OPCUAClientOptions,
    SecurityPolicy,
    TimestampsToReturn,
} from "node-opcua-client";

import * as opcua from "node-opcua";

async function main(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const options: OPCUAClientOptions = {
            connectionStrategy: {
                initialDelay: 1000,
                maxRetry: 100000,
            },
            securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.None,
            securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.None,
            endpoint_must_exist: false,
        };
        const client = OPCUAClient.create(options);
        await client.connect("opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:62544/Quickstarts/AlarmConditionServer");
        const session = await client.createSession();
        console.log("session created !");
        const subscription = ClientSubscription.create(session, {
            requestedPublishingInterval: 1000,
            maxNotificationsPerPublish: 100,
            publishingEnabled: true,
            priority: 10
        });
        var fields = [
            "EventId",
            "EventType",
            "SourceNode",
            "SourceName",
            "Time",
            "ReceiveTime",
            "Message",
            "Severity"
        ];
        var eventFilter = opcua.constructEventFilter(fields);
        var event_monitoringItem = await subscription.monitor(
            {
                nodeId: "ns=0;i=9764",
                attributeId: AttributeIds.EventNotifier
            },
            {
                queueSize: 100000,
                filter: eventFilter,
                discardOldest: true
            },
            TimestampsToReturn.Both
        );
        event_monitoringItem.on("changed", (dataValue: DataValue) => {
            const value = dataValue.value.value;
            console.log("Monitored item value (Event) changed: ", value);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Execution failed: ", err);
    }
}

main();
```

I've tried different node ids like `ns=0;i=9764` and `i=9764` but it's not working.

What am I missing? Is it just a node id issue (how should I get it from the event?) or I need to change the code in something different?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, i opened a [new issue](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/1220) in the official project github page.
The accepted solution shows how to directly point to the "Server" nodeid (ObjectIds.Server) in monitoring events.

I paste the solution code below:

```
import {
  AttributeIds,
  constructEventFilter,
  ObjectIds,
  OPCUAClient,
  TimestampsToReturn,
  Variant,
} from "node-opcua-client";

async function main(): Promise<void> {

  const client = OPCUAClient.create({});

  const endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://opcua.demo-this.com:62544/Quickstarts/AlarmConditionServer";

  const subscriptionParamters = {
    requestedPublishingInterval: 1000,
    maxNotificationsPerPublish: 100,
    publishingEnabled: true,
    priority: 10,
  };

  await client.withSubscriptionAsync(endpointUrl, subscriptionParamters, async (session, subscription) => {
      const fields = [
        "EventId",
        "EventType",
        "SourceNode",
        "SourceName",
        "Time",
        "ReceiveTime",
        "Message",
        "Severity",
      ];
      const eventFilter = constructEventFilter(fields);
      const event_monitoringItem = await subscription.monitor(
        {
          nodeId: ObjectIds.Server,
          attributeId: AttributeIds.EventNotifier,
        },
        {
          queueSize: 10,
          filter: eventFilter,
          discardOldest: true,
        },
        TimestampsToReturn.Both
      );

      event_monitoringItem.on("changed", (events: Variant[]) => {
        for(let i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
            console.log(fields[i],"=", events[i].toString());
        }
        console.log("----------------\n\n")
      });

      console.log("CTRL+C to stop");
      await new Promise<void>((resolve) => process.once("SIGINT", resolve));

    }
  );
}
main();
```